# Poisson process, initial condition, statinonarity, independent increments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

My book gives two definitions of the poisson process. From these definitions we get that the process starts at 0, at time 0, it is stationary and the time increments are independent. My question will be if we can get these three properties by just specifying the poisson distribution? I will make the question more clear with definitions and a clearer description of the problem.

> definition 1:
>
> The counting process {N(t), t $\ge$0} is said to be a poisson process have rate $\lambda, \lambda \ge 0$, if
>
> i) N(0) = 0
>
> ii) The process has independent increments.
>
> iii) The number of events in any interval of length t is Poisson
>   distributed with mean $\lambda t$. That is:
>   $P(N(t+s)-N(s)=n)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}$
>
> definition 2:
>
> i)N(0)=0
>
> ii) The process has stationary and independent increments.
>
> iii)$P(N(h)=1)=\lambda h+o(h)$
>
> iiii)$P(N(h)\ge 2)=o(h)$

Now comes my question. If we only define the process like this:

> alternative definition:
>
> $P(N(t)=n)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}$

**1. Can we then say that N(0) = 0? I mean if we accept that $0^{0}$ is 1, then it might work?**

If the answer is no to question 1, change the alternative definition to:

> alternative definition:
>
> i) N(0)=0
>
> ii) $P(N(t)=n)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}$

**2. Will this counting process be stationary?**

**3. Will this counting process have independent increments?**

Question 2 and 3 is most important to me. I have tried proving them but don't know how. Are they true?, and if so, are they difficult to prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your question:

1. Yes. This is fine, but it's just a matter of definition.
2. and 3.  No. But this is due to the fact that you are **not** defining a process. You only give the 1-dimensional distributions (i.e. for any $t\geq 0$) and this does not well-define a process$^{1)}$.
   This is what is presented in (ii) of your Definitions 1 and 2.

1) Compare this to a Gaussian variable $(X_1,X_2)$, where you only define the law of $X_1$ by its mean and variance and the law of $X_2$ by its mean and variance. Then you have not given the full covariance matrix only the diagonal party. You are missing the dependence structure.

However, if you have the finite-dimensional distributions then you can use the Daniell-Kolmogorov extension theorem to define a process, see [What is the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem good for?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94441/what-is-the-kolmogorov-extension-theorem-good-for)